# What determines if a machine is a force multiplier?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

Suppose I have a simple machine that has a Mechanical Advantage of 2, ideally.

That would mean its Velocity Ratio is 2, as well.

But practically speaking, it is  in very bad condition and has an efficiency of 10%, making its M.A. 0.2.

Would the machine still be considered a force multiplier (although effort = 5 * load)?

Comment: Theoretically (ie from the configuration of the machine) your machine is a force multiplier but practically due to its low efficiency it is not.

Comment: @Farcher If it is neither a force multiplier, nor a speed multiplier, and is not changing the direction or point of application, what is it doing? Moreover, how would a force multiplier be defined then -- a machine that has VR > 1, and not necessarily MA > 1, or is it dependent entirely on the practical MA? Is there any objectivity to it?

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is a perfectly clear question.

Comment: I completely agree with @HerrAlvé. 10th graders are taught a force multiplier is one which has MA>1 and VR>1